# How to apply a selected border style on a paragraph with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please need help on this.
I want to apply a border style selected from a list below on the paragraphe.
myFunction() doesn't work. What is missing ?

```
<p id="example">Test border style here !</p>

<select id="selectlist" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>none</option>
    <option>hidden</option>
    <option>dotted</option>
    <option>dashed</option>
    <option>solid</option>
    <option>double</option>
    <option>groove</option>
    <option>ridge</option>
    <option>inset</option>
    <option>outset</option>
</select>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = getElementById("selectlist").value;
   
    document.getElementById("example").Style.borderStyle = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should check the console by pressing `F12` on your keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of errors:

- You are missing the `document.` from before the first `getElementById`
- You are trying to access `Style` when the property is called `style`

Generally JavaScript error messages are quite helpful, so a good place to start is running your code and working through correcting any errors that appear in the console. I would also suggest reading a few tutorials regarding debugging JavaScript.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("selectlist").value;

  document.getElementById("example").style.borderStyle = x;
}
```

```html
<p id="example">Test border style here !</p>

<select id="selectlist" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option>none</option>
  <option>hidden</option>
  <option>dotted</option>
  <option>dashed</option>
  <option>solid</option>
  <option>double</option>
  <option>groove</option>
  <option>ridge</option>
  <option>inset</option>
  <option>outset</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `borderStyle` should be `border`

Comment: I believe `border` is just the shortcut style for multiple border related styles, and since only the `border-style` is being set (as opposed to color/thickness) `borderStyle` should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't though. I tried it with `border` and it worked. Try running your own snippet

Comment: Interesting, the snippet works in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Nevermind, I clicked hidden as the style, didn't realize what I clicked. `borderStyle` works fine